# Still Getting 'Must Declare Scalar Variable' Error After Declaring It

Tags: asp.net, sql

I'm trying to write some fairly simple ASP.NET code to manipulate data in an SQL Server 2012 database.  I've done it a hundred times before but for some reason this isn't working and it's driving me crazy.

I have the code below. The page loads and displays the data correctly. I can also successfully update records by amending the values in the `textboxes` and hitting the Update button.  But the Delete button will not work - every time I click it, I get the error **Must declare the scalar variable @PhoneNumberID**.  As you can see, I have included the variable in my DeleteParameters, and it's identical to the way I've declared it in my UpdateParameters, which seems to work fine!

```
<asp:Label ID="lblPersonID" runat="server" Text="2" /><br /><br />
<asp:ListView ID="lvEditPhoneNumbers" runat="server" DataSourceID="SQLEditPhoneNumbers" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblPhoneNumberID" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("PhoneNumberID")%>' />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEditPhoneNumberType" runat="server" DataSourceID="SQLPhoneNumberType" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="ID" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("PhoneNumberTypeID")%>' />
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLPhoneNumberType" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ContactsConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [PhoneNumberType] WHERE [Deleted] = 0"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditPhoneNumber" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("PhoneNumber")%>' CssClass="contactdetailseditfield" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDeletePhoneNumber" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/trash-26.png" Width="15px" Height="15px" ToolTip="Delete this phone number" CommandName="Delete" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLEditPhoneNumbers" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ContactsConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [PhoneNumbers] WHERE ([PersonID] = @PersonID) AND ([Deleted] = 0)"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [PhoneNumber] SET [PhoneNumber] = @PhoneNumber, [PhoneNumberType] = @PhoneNumberTypeID WHERE ([ID] = @PhoneNumberID)"
    DeleteCommand="UPDATE [PhoneNumber] SET [Deleted] = 1 WHERE ([ID] = @PhoneNumberID)" >
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblPersonID" Name="PersonID" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="PhoneNumberID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="PhoneNumberID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PhoneNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PhoneNumberTypeID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>            
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Yes, I know the way the data is displayed isn't pretty - I took this code out of the page it's supposed to appear on to try and figure out what's going on.  And yes, I know I've put an `UPDATE` command in the `DeleteCommand`, but I've done that in the past without problems (at least I think I have) and anyway, it works if I take out the paramaterised value in the command and replace it with an explicitly declared value.

Comment: Don't you have to specify the [**`DataKeyNames`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.datakeynames(v=vs.110).aspx) so it knows the unique identifier for a row?

Comment: I thought about that but decided it was a silly idea because 1) I was explicitly passing the unique identifier (PhoneNumberID) anyway and 2) The SQLDataSource is selecting from a query not a table. But I tried it just now and adding the DataKeyNames property has fixed it, so thank you!  Enter it as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using the DeleteItem function of a databound control (such as `ListView`), the [**`DataKeyNames`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.datakeynames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property is required to automatically bind the values of the parameters for deleting.  Otherwise, even though you have identified the `PhoneNumberID` as a parameter you need in the `DeleteCommand`, it is not actually being provided with a value, so it is still seen as not declared:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvEditPhoneNumbers"
              runat="server"
              DataSourceID="SQLEditPhoneNumbers"
              DataKeyNames="PhoneNumberID">
              ^^^^^  add this
```